# physics doesn't work in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This code creates a cannon and 3 balloons, the cannon should shoot out a bullet that'll destroy balloons, along with the words. DUring the process the cannon should rotate and when i release my finger from the screen it shoots. For some reason it doesn't respond, cannon not rotating nor any bullet is shot.

```
local score = 0
local scoreText
local scoreForLevelComplete
local background
local infoBar
local restartBtn
local cannon
local levelNum
local cannonCharge = {}
local shot = {}
local cannonBall
local impulse = 0
local balloons = {}
local cannonCharge = {}
local shot = {}


function scene:createScene(event)
    local group = self.view

    background = display.newImage( "bkg_clouds.png")
    group:insert(background)
    background.x = 230
    background.y = 195

    scoreText = display.newText( "0", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
    scoreText:setFillColor( 0,0, 0 )
    scoreText.x = 87
    scoreText.y = 28
    group:insert( scoreText ) 

    questionText = display.newText('a', display.contentCenterX, display.contentWidth/4, native.systemFont, 40)
    group:insert(questionText)

    infoBar = display.newImage ("infoBar.png")
    group:insert(infoBar)
    infoBar.x = 10
    infoBar.y = 25

    restartBtn = display.newImage ("restartBtn.png")
    group:insert(restartBtn)
    restartBtn.x = 470
    restartBtn.y = 300

    cannon = display.newImage ("cannon.png")
    group:insert(cannon)
    cannon.x = 10
    cannon.y = 270

    cannon.anchorX = 0.5
    cannon.anchorY = 0.5
    restartBtn.isVisible = true

    local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 125)
    group:insert(balloon)
    balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 175)
    group:insert(balloon)
    balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 225)
    group:insert(balloon)

    local balloonText1 = display.newText('\227\129\130', 495, 125)
    balloonText1:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
    local balloonText2 = display.newText('\227\129\132', 495, 170)
    balloonText2:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
    local balloonText3 = display.newText('\227\129\134', 495, 225)
    balloonText3:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )

    balloon.name = 'balloon'
    physics.addBody(balloon)
    balloon.bodyType = 'static'
    table.insert(balloons, balloon)      

    group:insert(balloonText1)
    group:insert(balloonText2)
    group:insert(balloonText3)


    function ballCollision(e)
       if (e.other.name == 'balloon') then
            scene.updateScore()
            e.target:removeSelf() 
            print ('remove balloon text')
            e.other:removeSelf()
            audio.play(pop)
        end
    end

    function cannonCharge:touch(e)
        if(e.phase == 'began') then
            impulse = 0
            cannon.isVisible = true
            Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        end
    end

    function charge()
        local degreesPerFrame = 0.5
        cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - degreesPerFrame 
        impulse=impulse-0.2

        if(cannon.rotation < -46) then
            cannon.rotation = -46
            impulse = -3.2
        end
    end

    function shot:touch(e)
        if(e.phase == 'ended') then
            Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
            cannon.isVisible = true
            cannon.rotation = 0

            cannonBall = display.newImage('cannon ball.png', 84, 220)
            physics.addBody(cannonBall, {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
            group:insert(cannonBall)

            -- Shoot cannon ball
            cannonBall:applyLinearImpulse(3, impulse, cannonBall.x, cannonBall.y )

            --Collision listener
            cannonBall:addEventListener ('collision', ballCollision)
        end
    end
end
```

This is my enterscene function

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    background:addEventListener('touch', cannonCharge)
    background:addEventListener('touch', shot) 
end
```

Comment: Sorry about the format, i edited it and also added a few event listeners but the balloons still wouldn't disappear after the ball hits them.

Comment: The function cannonCharge:touch(e) and function shot:touch(e) holds the objects, if thats what you mean. Also, only the third balloon disappear, the first two don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the Corona docs say that listener can be a table object when call `addEventListener('event', listener)` but I have never seen or used that. There is no advantage in posted code to have functions defined inside the createScene since they are global and you already have a bunch or module-local variables. Try pulling the listeners out and making them regular functions:

```
local canon
...
local cannonCharge = function(event)
    if event.phase == 'began' then
        impulse = 0
        cannon.isVisible = true
        Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
    end
end

local shot = function(event)
    ...
end

local function charge()
    ...
end

... other local functions ...

function scene:createScene(event)
    ...
end
```

Also, confirm that your touch listeners are being called by printing something inside each one.

Finally, and most importantly, you only added the last balloon to the physics so the bullet can only collide with that one balloon. The same way that you had to add `group:insert(balloon)` after each balloon created, you should have `physics.addBody(balloon, ...)` after each group insert. So do this:

```
local balloon1 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 125)
local balloon2 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 175)
local balloon3 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 225)

group:insert(balloon1)
group:insert(balloon2)
group:insert(balloon3)

physics.addBody(balloon1)
physics.addBody(balloon2)
physics.addBody(balloon3)

balloon1.bodyType = 'static'
balloon2.bodyType = 'static'
balloon3.bodyType = 'static'

table.insert(balloons, balloon1)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon2)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon3)
```

There is a lot of code duplication there, and adding more balloons requires many lines to change, so you might as well factor out the duplicate code into a function:

```
local function createBalloon(x, y)
    local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', x, y)
    group:insert(balloon)
    physics.addBody(balloon)
    balloon.bodyType = 'static'
    table.insert(balloons, balloon)      
end

createBalloon(495, 125)
createBalloon(495, 175)
createBalloon(495, 225)
```

which has the advantage that if you need more balloon you won't forget any settings, and any new settings put in createBallon so all balloons have same config (except for function parameters like x,y etc).

*Update: Determine which balloon in collision handler*

Depends why you need to know which of the balloons. For example if it's because balloon 1 gives 10 pts while 3 gives 30, then there are better ways: you can add your fields to objects, like you could have `balloon1.points` = 10, `balloon2.points` = 30 etc (you would make that a function argument of `createBalloon`) and in collision handler just use `score = score + e.other.points`. You should only need to use [Local Collision Handling](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#local-collision-handling) because only need to know when the cannon ball collides with balloons. To figure out if e.other is a balloon, easiest is to add a property when you create balloon:

```
local function createBalloon(x, y, balloonText)
    local balloon = ...
    ...
    balloon.isBalloon = true -- only balloon objects will have this
    balloon.label = balloonText
end
```

Couple notes on the above: another custom property is `label` since you want to remove the balloon text in the collision handler, easiest is to have a property for it. But do not remove objects involved in collision in the collision handler, as explained in [that document](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#local-collision-handling), use delayed removal. So your handler becomes

```
function ballCollision(e)
   if e.other.isBalloon then
        scene.updateScore(e.other.points)

        timer.performWithDelay(1, e.target.removeSelf, e.target) 
        timer.performWithDelay(1, e.other.removeSelf,  e.target) 

        e.other.label:removeSelf() -- this is ok: not involved in collision
        audio.play(pop)
    end
end
```

Comment: If i use add local at finction charge() it gives me an error, "assertion error" but if i don't use local, the ball only makes the third balloon disappear and not the first or second one.

Comment: Would it be better if i use balloon 1, 2, 3 if i want to compare which balloon that my bullet hit? For example, in ballCollision(e), i'll measure whether the the ball hit the second balloon so if (event.object1.name == 'balloon1') then...else if (event.object2.name == 'balloon2')then...

Comment: I'm trying to make it to a quiz game except i shoot the cannon the hit the right answer. Should I use event.other.name then? Seems like object1, object2 and object3 makes more sense.

Comment: @user3305142 Please see update for this clarification.

Comment: Theres an error with the string.match, it says bad argument#1 to 'match'(string expected, got nil).

Comment: Also could i change (e.other.name, 'balloon') to (e.other.name, 'balloon1') ? and have multiple if loops? I'm not sure how 'balloon' can be used to identify each balloons.

Comment: @user3305142 I updated to clarify, but this is going way beyond scope of your original question. It is time for you to close this question. If you have further questions, please re-read my answer carefully a couple times, follow the links, then try things on your own, and only then if you are still stuck, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared balloons as a array and using the balloon
 as a variable while assigning images to them. So you need to declare 3 separate balloon object like balloon text or if you are using array then you need to declare like this.

```
for i=1,3 do
  balloon[i] = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 225)
  group:insert(balloon[i])
end
```

So it will identify which balloon you want to shoot.

Comment: If thats the case, how do I insert all 3 balloons into balloons table since they all have different object names?

Comment: And the code also means that the 3 balloons will be spawning at the same location for 3 times.

Comment: No need to insert balloon in to balloons table because it's already table. And you can change your balloon location as per your choice. i.e use array for position or do mathematical calculation.

Comment: I understand now, so i assume i don't need the line of table insert and only have these codes: balloon.name = 'balloon[i]'     physics.addBody(balloon[i])   balloon.bodyType = 'static'

Comment: theres some problem with balloon.name = 'balloon[i], it gives me an error "attempt to index field"(a nil value)

Comment: You need to write balloon[i].name = balloon[i]